# Gitlab pipeline does not catch errors

Tags: node.js, shell, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline where I have failed test (on purpose):

```
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Failed Tests 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
 FAIL  tests/colorService.test.ts > Competitor color test > Test pipeline
AssertionError: expected '4' to deeply equal '6'
- Expected
+ Received
- 6
+ 4
 ❯ tests/colorService.test.ts:35:19
     33|         let k = "6"
     34| 
     35|         expect(r).toEqual(k)
       |                   ^
     36|     })
     37| })
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯[1/1]⎯
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
feature-pipeline:
  stage: feature-pipeline
  script:
    - chmod +x -R scripts
    - cd scripts
    - ./feature.sh
  only:
    - /feature.*$/
  except:
    - /develop.*$/
    - /release.*$/
    - /hotfix.*$/
```

feature.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
./install-dependencies-stats-all.sh
./test-all.sh
./build-all-dev.sh
```

Install dependencies I simply install them, test i run tests with vitests (npm).
So when tests fail the scrip keeps going.

Any ideas how can I catch erros in gitlab so pipeline actually fails?

Answer (score 1):

[Resolved] I added in every script the line:

```
set -e
```

In the beginning. Seem to stop pipeline whenever test fails.